# How do I craft a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to have a place to store my items in case I get full of items or die.

Comment: If there's anything you want to craft in Minecraft be sure to browse [the crafting page](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Crafting).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can craft a chest that can store up to 27 item stacks by following this recipe:
[image]

A good thing to note is that you can also place two chests side-by-side to create a larger version that has more storage space.

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest)

Comment: Ninja! *grumble*